# Setting ImageView' s size by phone screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

i want ImageView's to look same on different screen sizes. To make it easier for you to understand how it should look there are some image:

[image]

Biggest problem is that my imageViews are created programmatically. ImageViews layout and size are set by this code

```
LinearLayout LinearLayoutas = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);

         ImageView ImageViewas = new ImageView(this);

         ImageViewas.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
         LinearLayoutas.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         ImageViewas.setLayoutParams(params);
         ImageViewas.getLayoutParams().height = 650;
         ImageViewas.getLayoutParams().width = 950;
         params.setMargins(0, 50, 0, 0);
```

Any ideas how to change this code that my app can look same on diffrent screen sizes?

Comment: You can handle image's width with `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONTENT`. Then set your margin and it will work in every devices.

Comment: And what about height? I want it to be same on every ImageView

Comment: You cannot do it dinamicaly as with width. You'll have to do it as you've done in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can retrieve device resolution and set `imageView` width and height. Here is the solution.

```
private class ScreenResolution {
    int width;
    int height;
    public ScreenResolution(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
ScreenResolution deviceDimensions() {
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    // getsize() is available from API 13
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        return new ScreenResolution(size.x, size.y);
    }
    else {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();      
        // getWidth() & getHeight() are deprecated
        return new ScreenResolution(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
    }
}

..................

LinearLayout LinearLayoutas = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);

ImageView ImageViewas = new ImageView(this);

ImageViewas.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
LinearLayoutas.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

ScreenResolution screenRes = deviceDimensions();
ImageViewas.setLayoutParams(params);
ImageViewas.getLayoutParams().height = screenRes.height;
ImageViewas.getLayoutParams().width = screenRes.width;
params.setMargins(0, 50, 0, 0);
```

Also when the device orientation will be changed, the width and height should be swapped. You can do that in `onConfigurationChanged`:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfiguration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfiguration);
    // swap device width and height here and re-assign
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is realy helpfull! And one more thing to leave some space on right and left sides of ImageView i need to set margins?

Comment: Yes, you can set margin like that. But suppose if you want to set margin left and right 20 unit, then you should set the image width as `ImageViewas.getLayoutParams().width = screenRes.width - 20` to get the perfect match. Also if you found this answer helpful, accept it and/or upvote it.